# bash selective copy folders and content to another location

Tags: bash, file, copy, find

I'm looking for a bash scrypt to copy some folders and some of the content to another location. I'm a teacher and very noobish with programming language anyway what I'm looking for , I have this director structure

Main director "Students" with subfolders "john";"daisy";"work" etc .. and some of the folders contain a specific file for example "exam.dat" , I need a scrypt that will check every folder in students for the file "exam.dat" and copy that folder and this file to another location, without copying other files inside folders or  folders that doesn't contain exam.dat.

Hope I'm explicit enough. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "usage: cpexams directory"
    exit 1
fi

DESTINATION=$1

if [[ ! -d "${DESTINATION}" ]]; then
    echo "directory ${DESTINATION} does not exist!"
    exit 2
fi

for dir in *; do
    if [[ -d "${dir}" ]] && [[ -a "${dir}/exam.dat" ]]; then
        mkdir "${DESTINATION}/${dir}"
        cp "${dir}/exam.dat" "${DESTINATION}/${dir}/"
    fi
done
```

If you want to reuse the script on the **same** destination directory (meaning to update the destination directory) then change `mkdir` to `mkdir -p`

Comment: Parsing ls is also not at all necessary here as a simple `*` glob will work. This script also assumes it will be run from the `Student` directory where it might be better off to ask for that and assume the local directory for the destination or just ask for both.

Comment: Thx. fixed the ls. Other than that, if it won't be run from the students directory adding another arg as a src dir instead of `*` is easy. @AlinDraghici will manage. :)